# Pass Expression as a parameter into a Generic method, and plug the Expression into a CreateCriteria?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, generics, lambda

I have a generic method that exists in EntityRepository that gets entities by Name, which is defined as follows:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetEntitiesByName<T>(string searchExpression)
        where T : class, ISearchableEntity, new()
    {
            return  _session.CreateCriteria<T>()
                .Add(LambdaSubquery.Property<Fund>(x => x.Id)
                .AddNameSearchCriteria<T>(searchExpression)
                .List<T>();
    }
```

There are a number of services that use this method, and everything was fine.. but I now have a requirement that some services require more specific search capabilites than is available in this method.

So I'm wonder if it's possible for me to pass in a DetachedCriteria as an Expression (or something) that I could plug into the query? Each service that needs different functionality could pass in the expression it needs to.

I'm not hugely familiar with NHibernate or Expressions, so I might be out of my depth here. I'm mostly trying to get a feel for what's possible. Otherwise I'll have to abandon the generic method in favour of more specific Repository methods for each service. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a code sample in [my answer to a somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434338/expression-trees) which might help you. However, it is only a rough beginning. If you really want to translate full LINQ expressions into NHibernate and have some semblance of completeness, I would recommend to search for existing solutions first. A quick Google search found me this:

- [Implementing LINQ for NHibernate](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/03/17/Implementing-Linq-for-NHibernate-A-How-To-Guide--Part.aspx)