# Equality of custom expressions using Expression Trees

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

So this is the questions. This is similar to Regex: i have a pattern and could know does expression match. For example i have an image like this

[image]

So `Hello world` is match, but `Goodbye Town` doesn't.

How can i do it? I can build a tree like this, but i don't know how to use it to check does input match.

I've used a search, it's similar to this solve [Expression Trees in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434338/expression-trees)
but not at all.

Comment: Why do you think expression trees are well suited to solving this problem?

Comment: *"I can build a tree like this"* - plese post the code you use to build the tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an appropriate time to use the Composite pattern.  Create an expression interface and then classes for And, Or, and a single value.  You can then compose those classes to create your tree:

```
public interface IExpression
{
    bool Match(string value);
}

public class AndExpression : IExpression
{
    private IEnumerable<IExpression> expressions;

    public AndExpression(IEnumerable<IExpression> expressions)
    {
        this.expressions = expressions;
    }
    public bool Match(string value)
    {
        return expressions.All(exp => exp.Match(value));
    }
}
public class OrExpression : IExpression
{
    private IEnumerable<IExpression> expressions;

    public OrExpression(IEnumerable<IExpression> expressions)
    {
        this.expressions = expressions;
    }
    public bool Match(string value)
    {
        return expressions.Any(exp => exp.Match(value));
    }
}
public class ContainsExpression : IExpression
{
    private string search;
    public ContainsExpression(string search)
    {
        this.search = search;
    }

    public bool Match(string value)
    {
        return value.Contains(search);
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation of the tree you provided:

```
IExpression root = new AndExpression(new IExpression[]{
    new ContainsExpression("Hello"),
    new OrExpression(new IExpression[]{
        new ContainsExpression("World"),
        new ContainsExpression("Town")})});
```

Note that you can make some changes to the API to make constructing these trees a bit more terse, if you're suitably motivated.  (i.e. optional constructor overloads with params.)